# Joomla mailing list with referral plugin?

Tags: php, joomla

I've inherited a Joomla 1.5 site and I am trying to find a Joomla component that will let me add a signup/prizedraw page where people can also recommend the compo to a friend in the one form.

Basically

1 - email to go out to our existing database asking them to recommend a friend for the chance to win x prize
2 – they are directed to the form on the website where they enter their details for the prize draw and also have the option to enter a few friends email addresses
3 – the recommender is entered into the draw (signed up), while the recommended friends get a princes square email saying ‘you have been recommended by....to receive exclusive offers etc etc.. click here to enter.

Does anybody know if there any plugins out there that does this or is it a hand code jobby.

Cheers muchly.

Comment: Actually on second thoughts, it's just a simple email out when the insert signup database call is made. Think we'll just head down that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that it exactly matches your requirements.  But i would suggest you to have a look at AlphaUserPoints
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communities-a-groupware/membership/5949

Check it out.  Hope this will give you some direction.

Comment: Cheers SIA, this looks like a real time-saver.